# How can I make a Vue.js component react to a method fired from a Class object in data?

Tags: javascript, forms, vuejs2, vue-component, es6-class

*Disclaimer: I am pretty new to Vue.js, so this might be one of those dumb questions I should've been able to solve by myself. I apologize in advance if it is so.*

*I am also trying to use ES6, but I haven't gotten into it properly, so I'm sure my code is super messy. Sorry about that.*

---

I have built a simple wrapper around `<form>` and form elements like `<input>`, using Vue components. I have used [Jeffrey Way's `Form` and `Error` classes](https://github.com/laracasts/Vue-Forms) to deal with form submits and error handling.

According to Jeffrey's instructions I can bind the `submit` button's `disabled` attribute to a method on the `Error` class; `form.errors.any()`, referring to `form` in the component's `data` object, which contains an instance of `Form`. This method simply checks if there are any errors registered in an `Error` object bound to the `Form` object shared between all the components in the form.

So now if I submit the form and an error is returned, the button is disabled. But if I clear the errors, and even forcibly trigger the `any()` method, the submit button isn't re-enabled. I've made sure there are no errors, and the method works correctly and is returning false as expected (when the errors are cleared).

In addition to making sure all the other code is doing what I expected, I've tried searching Stack Overflow and Googling for examples of similar issues, but I found nothing. This might be because I'm not using the right search term.

If someone would kindly point out what I'm obviously missing here, and explain what I'm doing wrong, it would be very helpful.

**Here are the relevant snippets:**

*From `toru-form-submit.vue`*

```
<template>

    <button class="" :disabled="form.errors.any()">{{ text }}</button>

</template>

<script>

import {store, eventHub} from '../../../app';

export default {

  name: 'toru-form-submit',

  props: ['text'],

  data () {
    return {

        // Building a dummy object to prevent the component
        // from complaining before the Form object is ready
        form: { 'errors': {
                any() {}
            }
        }
    }
  },

  methods: {

    // If the form-mounted event was sent from this form,
    // point this.form to the related Form object in store
    init(id) {
        if (id == this.$parent.id) {
            this.form = store[this.$parent.id]
        };
    }
  },

  created: function () {

    // Wait for the parent element to get ready
    eventHub.$on('form-mounted', this.init);
  }
};
</script>
```

---

*From `toru-form.vue`*

```
mounted: function() {

    let elements = {};

    // Loops through all the child components of the form
    // and retrieves their name value
    for(let element in this.$children){

        if (this.$children[element].multiple === undefined || this.$children[element].multiple == 'false') {

            elements[this.$children[element].name] = '';

        } else {

            elements[this.$children[element].name] = [];

        }

    }

    // Instantiate a Form object and pass it an object
    // with all the names
    store[this.id] = new Form(elements);

    // Update the form component's data object to point
    // to the new Form object
    this.form = store[this.id];

    console.log(this.form);

    // Tell everyone that the form is mounted with a
    // Form object, and ready to go!
    eventHub.$emit('form-mounted', this.id);
  }
```

Comment: I am not really sure what dummy error data aims to do, since for me this is a case for computed properties https://jsfiddle.net/ue85ko3m/1/

Comment: @Hammster Thanks, that's a good workaround, and I think I'll use that instead. What I still don't get though, is why the value of disabled changes when form.errors.any() is called the first time, but not later?

And the dummy object is there because Vue complains about the method/property not existing otherwise. But I won't need it now I guess. :)